# polymer iron-form PUT method pass parameters in url

Tags: json, forms, polymer

I have a problem with my , I want to use the PUT method with json data but it's passing those parameters in the query string parameters and not in json, and I can't find my mistake. I'd like not to use 'iron-ajax' if possible.

```
            <form is="iron-form" method="put" action="http://localhost:5000/users/" id="loginForm" content-type="application/json">
              <paper-input name="username" label="Username" required auto-validate></paper-input>
              <paper-input name="password" label="Password" type="password" required auto-validate></paper-input>
              <paper-button raised onclick="_submit(event)" disabled id="loginFormSubmit">
                <paper-spinner id="spinner" hidden></paper-spinner>Submit</paper-button>
              <paper-button raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset</paper-button>
              <div class="output"></div>
            </form>
            <script>
              loginForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                loginFormSubmit.disabled = !loginForm.validate();
              });
              function _submit(event) {
                spinner.active = true;
                spinner.hidden = false;
                loginFormSubmit.disabled = true;
                Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
              }
              function _reset(event) {
                var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement
                form.reset();
                form.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = '';
              }
              document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
                spinner.active = false;
                spinner.hidden = true;
                loginFormSubmit.disabled = false;
                this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);
              });
              document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('iron-form-response', function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              });
            </script>
```

[image: polymer iron-form error]

thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iron-form` only includes the parameters in the body of `POST` requests. The simplest workaround is to change your `method="put"` to `method="post"`, and add a handler for `iron-form-presubmit` (fires after serialization) to change the method back to `PUT`.

```
form.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function() {
  this.request.method = 'put';
});
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qNEyvN?editors=0010)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! That worked very well but now the parameters are in the headers AND in the url. Do you have any idea how to get rid of that ? :) also do you know why there's 2 requests fired ? http://imgur.com/nDn1tKn

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. My tests show the parameters were moved from the URL to the body (and nowhere else). I only see 1 request. I'm guessing your code looks very much different than the snippet you've provided.

Comment: Ok thank you ! :) this snippet comes from the polymer doc.